# relevant hexids inside a hexagon

Tags: h3

i am generating a set of hex ids via "h3.geoToH3(lng, lat, res)".
after that i am creating a FeatureCollection via "let polygons = geojson2h3.h3SetToFeatureCollection(hexIds)"
When i am clicking on a hexagon on the map i just want the ids of the relevant hexagons inside the initiated hexagon.
How can i do that in a performant way?

```
getHexIds = (res) => {
        let hexIds = this.props.stations.features.map(element => {
            const [lng, lat] = element.geometry.coordinates;
            const hexId = h3.geoToH3(lng, lat, res);
            return hexId;
        })

        let polygons = geojson2h3.h3SetToFeatureCollection(hexIds);

        this.setState({
            polygons: polygons
        }, () => {
            this.geoJsonLayer.current.leafletElement.clearLayers().addData(this.state.polygons);
        })

        // console.info(this.state.polygons, res);
    }
```

```
onEachFeature = (feature, layer) => {
        layer.on('click', (e) => {
          // show the relevant hexids
        }) 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, this might have more to do with your map library (presumably Leaflet) than H3, but here are some general approaches:

- If you want to get the H3 index at the point where the user clicked, find the lat/long (probably something your map library provides in the click event) and then just run it through `h3.geoToH3(lat, long)` again. This is very fast, and it's much easier to recalculate it than to store it and look it up.
- If you want to get a *set* of H3 indexes associated with the click point (i.e. you have multiple features, each made up of multiple H3 indexes), then you usually want to build a reverse index like `{[h3Index]: h3Set}`. Then you can use `h3.geoToH3` to find the index at the click point, and look that up in your reverse index to find the set.
- If your map doesn't give you lat/long on click, you can use a library like [viewport-mercator-project](https://github.com/uber-common/viewport-mercator-project) to find the lat/long from the x/y screen coordinates of the click (available on the DOM event).